# Custom title moved down after surfaceview initialization in Android

Tags: android, surfaceview, title

In the main activity, LayoutParams is used for surfaceview management.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                    R.layout.custom_speedo);

            setContentView(R.layout.custom_speedo);
            myView = (MySurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.msurfaceView);
```

In .xml, Relative layout is assigned

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">


    <com.example.android.BluetoothChat.MySurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/msurfaceView"
        style="?android:background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_left_text"
        style="?android:attr/windowTitleStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_right_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It is confused that the title moved down immediately after the surfaceview initialization, see my screenshots.
before surfaceview created
[image]

After surfaceview
[image]

Comment: not sure what you really mean but maybe [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN) description can help. try to remove `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN` flag and check if its what you want!

Comment: Hi, @EbrahimKarimi.  You see (in the snapshot) there is a gray bar seems to hold the title. The title appears there before the surfaceview coming. But the title then shows outside the gray bar after surfaceview initialization. Actually, it shows 25dp down from the gray bar, which was specified to the surfaceview in .xml. That is actually the top part of the surface view.